# Two users are able to purchase item with 1 quantity when pay button is pressed at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, concurrency, firebase-realtime-database

When two different users click the pay button, the are both registered as successfully buying that item despite their only being one quantity of that item left.

I am checking if the item is available in my database, once a item is bought the quantity bought is minus from the database.

Code for my pay button:

```
  let currentShoeRefSizes = DataService.ds.DATABASE_REF_SHOES.child("currentShoes").child(self.shoe.shoeId).child("sizes")

                        for (size,quantity) in self.shoe.databaseFormattedShoeSize {
                            //SIZE IN ACTUAL FORMAT
                            var sizeToChange = size
                            sizeToChange.insert(".", at: size.index(before: size.endIndex))

                            if "\(self.selectedSize)" == sizeToChange{
                                let currentSizeRef = currentShoeRefSizes.child(size)
                                currentSizeRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                                    if let quantity =  snapshot.value as? Int {
                                        if quantity > 0 {
                                            self.getCustomerInformation()
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

My Get Customer Information Function:

```
//FUNCTIONS
    func getCustomerInformation() {
        //Get Customer Id
        let currentUserRef = DataService.ds.DATABASE_REF_USERS.child(CURRENTUSER!).child("customerId")
        currentUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let customerId = snapshot.value as! String
           self.chargeCustomer(customerId: customerId)


        })
    }
```

My ChargeCustomer Function:

```
func chargeCustomer(customerId: String) {
        //Send the token to a server
        let serverUrl = "HIDDEN"
        let params = ["amount": "\(Int(shoe.shoePrice * 100))", "currency": "cad", "description" : "Single Purchase","customerId": customerId,"requestType": "singleCharge"]
        Alamofire.request(serverUrl, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response.response!) // HTTP URL response

        }
        //TODO: CHECK IF PAYMENT WENT THROUGH THEN DELETE IT FROM THE CART AND ADD TO ORDERS
        //Add Items to the completed orders
        let currentUserOrderRef = DataService.ds.DATABASE_REF_USERS.child(CURRENTUSER!).child("orders")

        let shoeDataToAdd = ["shoeName": shoe.shoeName,
                                 "shoePrice": shoe.shoePrice,
                                 "shoeProductImageUrl": shoe.shoeProductImageUrl,
                                 "size": self.selectedSize,
                                 "status": "Not Shipped Yet"
                ] as [String : Any]
            currentUserOrderRef.child(shoe.shoeId).updateChildValues(shoeDataToAdd)


        //Remove Quanitity Amount from database
            let currentShoeRef = DataService.ds.DATABASE_REF_SHOES.child("currentShoes").child(shoe.shoeId)
            for (size,quantity) in shoe.databaseFormattedShoeSize {
                //SIZE IN ACTUAL FORMAT
                var sizeToChange = size
                sizeToChange.insert(".", at: size.index(before: size.endIndex))

                if "\(selectedSize)" == sizeToChange{
                    let currentSizeRef = currentShoeRef.child("sizes").child(size)
                    let newQuantity = quantity - 1
                    currentSizeRef.setValue(newQuantity)
                }

            }
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "successPage", sender: nil)

    }
```

Comment: Its hard to tell with certainty but there must be some lag between when your checking if the shoe is available, initiating the purchase, and then removing the purchased pair of shoes from inventory. You may need to set it up so that when you make your first call in the transaction flow that you take the item and put it on hold somewhere else in DB. Then if the transaction does go through you remove it from there, if it doesn't then you add it back to the available pile. That should stop another transaction from going through.

Comment: Hey Justin, just gave this a try and what happend it both recognized that there is one quanitty and both users sent a remove request to the database

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is a situation where you need control over backend logic to handle the situation. There is still lag in making request to see if it exists, then getting the response, then sending another request to remove it. Both users are getting an initial response that it exists before another request gets there telling the DB to place the item on hold. Off the top of my head to try and get around it your first request may need to be to remove one, then check again to see if the number is greater than -1. You need to find a way to change the number on the first request you make